# What should I do to see static and dynamic binding in action? [C++]

Tags: c++, gcc, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I am using GCC on  Linux.

I wish to understand working Virtual functions.

What kind of C++ code should I write to see and understand how exactly static and dynamic binding happens with and without Virtual functions?

And how to "see" how they were finally bound and what exactly happened during the process?

Comment: Static and dynamic linking are largely orthogonal to virtual and non-virtual functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think he means static versus dynamic *binding*.

Comment: @5gon12eder Is there a difference between linking and binding?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Linking is how the linker / loader puts together your executable so that a particular function has a definition at a known place.  Binding is the process of deciding which function to call in the first place.

Comment: @5gon12eder Wow, I didn't know that, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @5gon12eder Is the question fine now?

Comment: Dynamic binding is also called dynamic dispatch.  I don't know what is the more popular term.  Yes, I think it's fine now.  Though I would have understood you wanted to ask that from the beginning.

Comment: Now we have discussed the title, I think your question is a little broad to answer.  Did you work through a general book on C++ programming to understand the principle of run-time polymorphism?  [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) has detailed discussions on many topics but you are expected to have some basic knowledge first.  I've heard [a very good lecture on object orientation](https://pp.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/lehre/SS2013/foo/?lang=de) in general.  Unfortunately it's not in English.  In conclusion: I'm not quite sure what level of information you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. You can build and run this code with the function set to be a virtual function or not. To get virtual behavior, dynamic dispatch, dynamic binding, build it with the preprocessor macro `IS_VIRTUAL` defined. To see static binding build it without defining that macro.

```
#include <iostream>

#if defined(IS_VIRTUAL)
#define CONDITIONAL_VIRTUAL virtual
#else
#define CONDITIONAL_VIRTUAL
#endif

struct A {
  CONDITIONAL_VIRTUAL void foo() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : A {
  CONDITIONAL_VIRTUAL void foo() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

// global objects
A a; B b;

enum object_type { get_A, get_B };
A *get_object(object_type t) {
  switch (t) {
    case get_A: return &a;
    case get_B: return &b;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Choose A or B: ";
  char c;
  std::cin >> c;

  A *x = get_object( c == 'A' ? get_A : get_B );
  x->foo();
}
```

The binding is relevant to the evaluation of `x->foo()`. The compiler has to figure out what code to execute for that expression. With both static and dynamic binding, the compiler looks at `x` and sees its type is `A*`, so it looks at the `struct A` and looks for a `foo()` declaration.

With static binding the compiler finds that `foo()` is not `virtual`, so the compiler just goes ahead and generates code calling that `foo()` method. Simple.

With dynamic binding, the compiler sees that method marked as `virtual`, and so the compiler instead generates code which will, at runtime, use a table of function pointers associated with the object `x` to select the method to call, and then call whatever method is found. The compiler also generates code elsewhere to create tables for the global `a` and `b` objects. For the global `a` object it makes the table point to `A::foo()`, and for the global `b` it makes the table point to `B::foo()`. So if `x` points to `b` object then the table look-up will result in `B::foo()` and that's the function that will get called.

In general the compiler has to make sure that all objects which have virtual methods also have a table with them that points to the right functions to call, so that any time a virtual call is made on an object the program can, at runtime, get the table associated with the object and look up the the right method to call.

So build the above program in both static and dynamic modes, and then run it and observe the output you get for each input. Fill in the table below with the output you get for each combination of input and type of binding.

```
       Binding |   static     dynamic
Input
-----
A                    ?           ?
B                    ?           ?
```

In all cases the output is produced by the evaluation of the same `x->foo()` method call. In which cases is dynamic binding in evidence? Does this correspond with your understanding of the above explanation of dynamic binding?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Base {
public:
    int Foo();
    virtual int Bar();
};

class D1 : public Base {
public:
    int Foo();
    virtual int Bar();
};

class D2 : public Base {
public:
    int Foo();
    virtual int Bar();
};

main()
{
    Base * b = (rand() < 100) ? new D1 : new D2;
    // Always calls Base::Foo()
    b->Foo();
    // Call either D1::Bar() or D2::Bar()
    b->Bar();
}
```

Comment: You don't delete your object and if you did it would be wrong because you have no virtual destructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for the input, but the question was about binding and not how to write a complete class.  Adding all the methods a class should have make the answer less clear.

Comment: It's better to have a "less clear" answer that does not encourage bad things to happen.